# How to write a Windows command line with redirection operators (angle brackets) into a text file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to know how to write a Window command line with redirection operators into a text file?

My command line to write into file text file is:

```
echo (name / file1.txt >> file2.txt) >> filetot.txt
```

The part in parentheses is the part I want to write into file `filetot.txt`.

But unfortunately it doesn't record anything after the first `>>`.

Comment: there are some chars that have a special meaning. To echo them literally, you have to escape them with a caret: `echo name / file1.txt ^>^> file2.txt >> filetot.txt`

Answer (score -1):

How does this do for you?

```
REM rest of your code
(name / file1.txt >> file2.txt) >> filetot.txt
echo (name / file1.txt >> file2.txt) >> filetot.txt
```

We are still issuing your command, but also `echo`ing which command we are issuing to the `filetot.txt` file you specified.